# HTML website crashes on JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, html, crash

Whenever I load the website located [here](http://www.presentation.bugs3.com/presentation.html), the screen turns almost completely black and crashes. Along with this, the linked server page also crashes. Can I get some help finding the error. I have checked multiple validation sites, and none of them show an error.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.titletext{
color:white;
display:block;
position:absolute;
font-size:50px;
width:1000px;
margin-left:150px;
margin-right:200px;
}
.nametext{
color:white;
display:block;
position:absolute;
font-size:30px;
width:600px;
margin-left:500px;
margin-right:200px;
margin-top:600px;
}
.earthphoto{
display:block;
position:absolute;
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:150px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="update()">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.body.style.background="black";
var changescene=function(){
var allvariables=Object.keys( window );
if(page===1){
}
page++;
};
var page=1;
var x=0;
var update=function(){
if(page===1){
document.body.innerHTML="";
var text=document.createElement("p");
var textclass = document.createAttribute("class");
textclass.value="titletext";
text.setAttributeNode(textclass);
text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Welcome to Mikey's Google Earth Presentation!"));
document.body.appendChild(text);
var text2=document.createElement("p");
text2class=document.createAttribute("class");
text2class.value="nametext";
text2.setAttributeNode(text2class);
text2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("By Mikey Richards"));
document.body.appendChild(text2);
googleearthimage=document.createElement("img");
googleearthimage.setAttribute("src","EARTH.png");
googleearthimage.setAttribute("class","earthphoto");
document.body.appendChild(googleearthimage);
var music=document.createElement("audio");
var musiclink=document.createElement("source");
musiclink.src="Test.mp3";
music.appendChild(musiclink);
var musicclass=document.createAttribute("id");
musicclass.value="sound1";
music.setAttributeNode(musicclass);
document.body.appendChild(music);
if(x===0){
document.getElementById("sound1").play();
x++;
}
if(document.getElementById("sound1").duration===document.getElementById("sound1").currentTime){
changescene();
}
}
else if(page===2){
document.body.innerHTML="";
}
update();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an endless recursion. You unconditionally call `update()` from itself.

```
var update=function(){
    if(page===1) {
    // your code 
    }
    else if(page===2){
        document.body.innerHTML="";
    }
    update();
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want to continually call the update function. This way, it can work like a setInterval() while making it so that it merely repeats when everything has been run. This way, I can play the audio element I created in the code without it being restarted every few seconds and making it so I can change the page variable on the end of the audio. How can I make it so I can play the audio until the end and then change the page on the end?

Comment: Massive recursion exhausts your stack (if nothing else).  Can you have it as a loop?

Comment: Okay. I figured out how I am supposed to do it. What it does now is onLoad for the body runs update, update runs a function playing the first set of music, music has event listener that runs changescene on end, changescene runs update function, and so on.

Comment: Yeah. I thought that some sort of event listening should be used instead of endless recursion or endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the black screen is most likely due to the first line in your script tag:

```
document.body.style.background="black";
```

As for the actual page crash your function "update" endlessly calls itself, causing an infinite recursion.